# Generic(s) confusion: Type of this in generic superclass is not defined at compile time?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Just met this piece of code:

```
public class Container <T extends Containter<T>> {
    protected Map<String, Rule> inspect (T t) {
        // ....
    }
    public boolean isValid () {
        // ...
        inspect ((T)this);
        // ...
    }
}
```

What I'm confused about is the "isValid"-method.

When you replace the line with `inspect(this);` it won't compile: *incompatible types: Container <T> cannot be converted to T.*

In subclasses the error does not occur. So I'm asking myself: Could there be a situation where `this` is of Type other than Container? I mean what would be the type of `this` in the code above? The explicit cast seems to be unnecessary.

Hope you guys can understand me, I find it hard to explain stuff like that in english.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

First, thank you and sorry for letting you wait.

There was confusion about the intention of the inspect method. It is supposed to work on  the Container itself (not on the generic Type). Basically only subclasses of Container should be able to use it. So the whole thing is about inheritance.

It's about type safety for sub classes using the inspect method.

Imagine an instantiation like (**inside the Container's inspect-method**):

```
List<T> listOfSimilarContainers = new LinkedList<T>();
```

Now, if there was a subclass like

```
public class SubContainer extends Container<SubContainer> { }
```

calling inspect on that class should force the listOfSimilarContainers inside the inspect method to only contain SubContainers.

That is what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: this refers to the container, where as `T` is referring to the contents is my guess.   You would want to inspect the container, or inspect an element of the container.  If you inspect the container itself, it isnt of type `T`, as much as it is of type `Container`.  You would want to say:   `inspect(Container<T> t)`, and then call it:   `inspect(this);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simplified version:

```
interface Foo<T extends Foo<T>> { }
class Bar implements Foo<Bar> { }
class Baz implements Foo<Bar> { }
```

Note that `Baz` inherits from `Foo<Bar>` and not from `Foo<Baz>`. The code compiles without any errors.

In other words, the declaration of the interface does not guarantee, that `T` is the subclass of `Foo<T>`.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a scenario where this guarantee does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

How should work inspect method? If you want to inspect the generic type, then T could be a `Class<T>` object, else inspect's signature sholud be:

```
 public class Container<T extends Container<T>> {
        protected Map<String, String> inspect(Container<T> t) {
        }
        public boolean isValid() {
            // ...
            inspect(this);
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not @Sotirios Delimanolis? I don't know the purpose of inspect method. But anyway you can do:
'Class<T> clazz;
    protected Map<String, String> inspect(Class<T> t){...};
  public boolean isValid() {
        // ...
        inspect(clazz);
   }'

Comment: If the method is declared to accept a parameter `T t`, then `T` cannot be `Class` since `T` has bounds of `Container<T>`.

Comment: That's why i ask for the intention os inspect() method. If it has to inspect a Container<T> or the generic type T. In the second option you have to pass the class to inspect in this way.